# java error unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: java, awt

I am having a problem with using awt tools in java. There are no errors when I finish and run a code but when I click a button that i make this shows the "[AWTView javaRole]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fad4072cb30"

Im using jdk 1.8 version and latest eclipse version with using m1 pro mac

> ```
> import java.awt.*;
> public class Grade {
>   public static void main(String args[]) {
>       Frame frame = new Frame("informaton input program");
>       frame.setSize(450, 150);
>       frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
>       
>       
>       Label Ib1 = new Label("Please Select your grade");
>       
>       
>       Choice ch = new Choice();
>       ch.add("1 grade");
>       ch.add("2 grade");
>       ch.add("3 grade");
>       ch.add("4 grade");
>       
>       Button btn = new Button("Submit");
>       Button btn2 = new Button("Search");
>       
>       frame.add(Ib1);
>       frame.add(ch);
>       frame.add(btn);
>       frame.add(btn2);
>       frame.setVisible(true);
>   }
> }
> ```

when I click a button or Choice ch that I made, It shows the error like this

> java[18717:636221] -[AWTView javaRole]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff777758790

Comment: This is not an Eclipse problem.  It shouldn't be tagged with `[eclipse]`.

Comment: For what it is worth, I cannot reproduce the problem.   Try compiling and running the program from a command shell.  It works for me with Java 8 & Java 17 on Linux.   It might be a problem with your Java installation ...